# WCF write to IIS logs without blocking the request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

I have a requirement where I want to log the response of WCF method to IIS log against the current request. This is currently implemented but the problem is I have to serialize response object before logging it as AppendToLog method only takes string input parameter and this serialization taking most of the time. This is adding significant delay to the overall response time.

I want to understand if there is any way I can do this logging after I return the response to client ? I tried to do it asynchronously just before the return statement but this is not working as Current Context goes null.

Please let me know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you consider other logging methods other than built-in?

Comment: Hi Opewix, I can not consider other logging methods at this moment.As other tools are configured to read IIS logs only.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clone the `CurrentContext` object and then pass the cloned copy into the async method you referenced? Or put the values you want from the the context object into separate variables and then pass those variables into the async method directly.

You will definitely want to load test that... if the serialization is taking too long and the end-point gets called too much your number of threads could grow pretty high.

Comment: Thanks for reply. the only reason I am using current context is to log data to iis using httpcontext.current.response appendtolog() api. I don't think I can do this with cloned context object.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to delegate the LogWriting to a different thread in your app. 
This way you can push your object to a Logging Queue and carry on with the call.

The thread handling the log writing can append to logs at its own pace.